# Помогите понять код: алгоритм генерации матрицы со спиралью

Tags: python, алгоритм, матрицы

Не могу понять как именно работает код.Очень прошу написать комментарии к каждой строке кода(если не затруднит),что бы понять сам алгоритм выполнения

Задача:

Выведите таблицу размером n×n, заполненную числами от 1 до n2 по спирали, выходящей из левого верхнего угла и закрученной по часовой стрелке

Сам код:

```
def zm(n):
    dx, dy = 1, 0
    x, y = 0, 0
    arr = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(1, n**2+1):
        arr[x][y] = i
        nx, ny = x+dx, y+dy
        if 0 <= nx < n and 0 <= ny < n and not arr[nx][ny]:
            x, y = nx, ny
        else:
            dx, dy = -dy, dx
            x, y = x+dx, y+dy
    for x in list(zip(*arr)):
        print(*x)

zm(int(input()))
```

Comment: связанный вопрос: [creating a spiral array in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36834505/4279)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36834505/creating-a-spiral-array-in-python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
# Создаётся функция, которая и будет всё делать
def zm(n):
    # Переменной dx присваивается значение 1
    # Переменной dy присваивается значение 0
    # Обычно dx и dy - это некие приращения для переменных x и y
    dx, dy = 1, 0
    # Переменным x и y присваивается значение 0
    x, y = 0, 0
    # Создаётся список списков
    # Это матрица n*n
    # Пока все её элементы - пустые (None)
    arr = [[None] * n for _ in range(n)]
    # Выполняется перебор
    # Для переменной i последовательно перебираем значения от 1 до (n-квадрат + 1)
    for i in range(1, n**2+1):
        # Элементу матрицы с координатами x и y присваивается значение i
        # Эта строчка будет присваивать последовательные натуральные числа
        # тем ячейкам, которые перебирает код чуть ниже
        arr[x][y] = i
        # Создаются временные переменные nx и ny
        # в которых вычисляются новые значения для x и y
        # для этого к старым значенииям прибавляются приращения
        nx, ny = x+dx, y+dy
        # Если всё нормально, и индекс не выскочил за пределы матрицы
        # или не наткнулся на уже занятую ячейку
        if 0 <= nx < n and 0 <= ny < n and not arr[nx][ny]:
            # то эти значения и оставляются
            x, y = nx, ny
        else:
            # а если индекс выскочил за границу матрицы
            # или наткнулся на уже занятую ячейку
            # то разворачиваемся на 90 градусов
            # путем замены приращения по x и y друг на друга
            # а минус нужен, чтобы он не ходил только вправо или вниз, 
            # а чередовал с движениями вверх или влево. 
            # Так и получается спираль 
            dx, dy = -dy, dx
            # и используем уже это изменённое движение для новых значений x и y
            x, y = x+dx, y+dy
    # После того, как перебрали все элементы, 
    # печатаем то, что получилось
    for x in list(zip(*arr)):
        print(*x)

# А здесь вся вышеописанная функция
# вызывается с аргументом, который вводит пользователь с клавиатуры
zm(int(input()))
```

Comment: Комментарии типа: *"Переменной dx присваивается значение 1"* не являются слишком полезными *"чтобы понять сам алгоритм выполнения."* Если автор вопроса не понимает, что `dx, dy = 1, 0` делают в Питоне, тогда вопрос должен быть задан именно об этой конструкции, иначе текущий вопрос слишком широким бы был (адекватный ответ это вводное руководство по Питону для новичков в программировании или даже целая книга, что находится за рамками Stack Overflow ответа). Лучшим комментарием для объяснения алгоритма могло бы быть: `dx, dy = 1, 0 # первоначальное направление движения: направо (Восток)`

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое дополнение – можно сформировать вывод с закручивание по спирали против часовой стрелки. Кому-то может пригодиться.

Эти два вывода равносильны (закручивание по часовой стрелке):

```
for x in list(zip(*arr)):
    print(*x)


for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[j][i], end=" ")
    print()

# Пример для n = 5:

# 1 2 3 4 5
# 16 17 18 19 6
# 15 24 25 20 7
# 14 23 22 21 8
# 13 12 11 10 9
```

Вариант с закручивание против часовой стрелки:

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(len(arr)):
        print(arr[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

# 1 16 15 14 13 
# 2 17 24 23 12 
# 3 18 25 22 11 
# 4 19 20 21 10 
# 5 6 7 8 9
```