# Заполнение двумерного массива по спирали СИ

Tags: c, массивы

Хочу заполнить двумерный массив по спирали. Ввожу число, затем генерируется двумерный массив, который заполняется от единицы до этого числа. Следующие элементы массива, если они есть, заполняются нулями. Однако, код работает не всегда. Например, если массив 3*4 а введенное число равно 65, результат показывается некорректно. Что в коде не так?
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

void spiral(int array[100][100], int m, int n, int s)
{
int size, b, x = 0, y = 1, num = 1;
size = m*n;
    for (num=1;num<=size+1;num++)
    {  
        for (b = x; b < n; b++)
        {
            if (num <=s) {
                array[x][b] = num;
                num++;
            }
            else array[x][b] = 0;
        }

        if (num == size + 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (b = y; b < m; b++)
        {
            if (num <=s) {
                array[b][n - 1] = num;
                num++;
            }
            else array[b][n - 1] = 0;
        }

        if (num == size + 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        y++;
        n--;

        for (b = n - 1; b > x; b--)
        {
            if (num <= s) {
                array[m - 1][b] = num;
                num++;
            }
            else array[m - 1][b] = 0;
        }

        if (num == size + 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        for (b = m - 1; b > x; b--)
        {
            if (num <= s) {
                array[b][x] = num;
                num++;
            }
            else array[b][x] = 0;
        }
        x++;
        m--;
    }
}
int main()
{   int m, n, s, array[100][100];
srand(time(NULL));
//m=3;
// n=4;
m = 2 + rand() % 5;
n = 2 + rand() % 5;
//memset(array, 0, sizeof(array[0][0]) * 10 * 10);
printf("enter the number \n");
scanf("%i", &s);
spiral(array, m, n, s);

for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
{                                                                          
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("%i\t", array[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

return (0);
 }`
```

Comment: Воспользуйтесь дебаггером и найдете проблему.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [Помогите понять код: алгоритм генерации матрицы со спиралью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/564644/23044)

Comment: `spiral(int array[100][100],...` никогда так не делайте в Си.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[,] FillMatrixtoSpiral(int row, int col)
{
    int[,] array = new int[row, col];

    int Up = 0;    // Сужение сверху
    int Down = 0;  // Сужение снизу
    int Left = 0;  // Сужение слева
    int Right = 0; // Сужение справа

    // Переменные счетчики используемые в расчетах
    int k = 1; // Счетчик, который присваивает значение элемнетам массива
    int i = 0; // Координары строки
    int j = 0; // Координаты столбца

    while (k <= row * col)
    {
        array[i, j] = k;

        // Проверка возможности движения вправо
        if (i == Up && j < col - Right - 1)
            ++j; // производится движение по столбцу вправо

        // Проверка возможности движения вниз
        else if (j == col - Right - 1 && i < row - Down - 1)
            ++i; // производится движение по строкам вниз

        // Проверка возможности движения влево
        else if (i == row - Down - 1 && j > Left)
            --j; // производится движение по столбцу влево

        // Проверка возможности движения вверх
        else
            --i; // производится движение по строкам вверх

        // Сужение диапазона, если окружность заполнена
        if ((i == Up + 1) && (j == Left) && (Left != col - Right - 1))
        {
            ++Up;
            ++Down;
            ++Right;
            ++Left;
        }
        ++k; // Счетчик увеличен на 1
        // Цикл начинается заново
    }
    return array;
}

// Блок вывода элементов двумерного массива
void PrintArray(int[,] array)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < array.GetLength(0); ++x)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < array.GetLength(1); ++y)
        {
            System.Console.Write(array[x, y] + "\t");
        }
        System.Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

// Основной блок программы
int[,] SpiralArray = FillMatrixtoSpiral(4, 4);
PrintArray(SpiralArray);
```

Comment: Но вопрос по си...